# Unable to declare libname with an XLS file in SAS?

Tags: excel, sas, enterprise-guide

I am trying to declare a libname in SAS that points to an XLS file so that I can reference the individual sheets in my code (I really just need to populate them as tables in dictionary.tables to do what I need).  I have tried using the XLSX and EXCEL engine in the libname statement and neither of those seem to be working.

When I run the following code, I receive an error:

```
libname excellib excel "/my/path/excel_file.xls";
```

[ERROR: The EXCEL engine cannot be found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSgMo.png)

When I run the same code with the xlsx engine, the libname is successfully assigned, but there are no tables in the library even though there are many sheets in the excel workbook.

Anyone had this issue before? Thanks!!

Comment: do you _have_ the excel engine? XLSX will obviously not work with xls files.

Comment: What are you running SAS on?  Is this local PC SAS, or is this EG connecting to a server, and what kind of server if so?

Comment: Also worth checking that you have SAS/ACCESS to PC Files licensed.  Try running `proc setinit; run;` to find out.  If it isn't then you will get the error you are seeing, as this is a requirement to access the Excel engine

Comment: I don't think you can use the libname method to access an xls file on a server, since you've tagged EG, I'm guessing you're on a server. This limitation does not apply to the XLSX engine.

Comment: Excel libname engine should work on a Windows server, not sure about Unix.

Comment: There are also the "xls" and "excelcs" engines that could be appropriate, depending on your configuration. If none works, make sure the pc files server is running as a Windows service on your machine.